Is there any way to have no /en prefix for English language while having other prefix like /de for German language
I am using i18next with next js app routing there should be /de prefix for German language but no prefix for English
This is my index.js file inside the /i18n folder which also exports useTranslation hook for translation
//app/i18n/index.js

import { createInstance } from "i18next";
import resourcesToBackend from "i18next-resources-to-backend";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next/initReactI18next";
import { getOptions } from "./settings";


const initI18next = async (lng, ns) => {
  const i18nInstance = createInstance();
  await i18nInstance
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .use(
      resourcesToBackend((language, namespace) =>
        import(`./locales/${language}/${namespace}.json`)
      )
    )
    .init(getOptions(lng, ns));
  return i18nInstance;
};


export async function useTranslation(lng, ns, options = {}) {
  const i18nextInstance = await initI18next(lng, ns);
  return {
    t: i18nextInstance.getFixedT(
      lng,
      Array.isArray(ns) ? ns[0] : ns,
      options.keyPrefix
    ),
    i18n: i18nextInstance,
  };
}


and this is the middleware file on the root folder
//middleware.js

import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import acceptLanguage from 'accept-language'
import { fallbackLng, languages, cookieName } from './app/i18n/settings'

acceptLanguage.languages(languages)

export const config = {
  // matcher: '/:lng*'
  matcher: ['/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|assets|favicon.ico|sw.js|site.webmanifest).*)']
}

export function middleware(req) {
  let lng
  if (req.cookies.has(cookieName)) lng = acceptLanguage.get(req.cookies.get(cookieName).value)
  if (!lng) lng = acceptLanguage.get(req.headers.get('Accept-Language'))
  if (!lng) lng = fallbackLng

  // Redirect if lng in path is not supported
  if (
    !languages.some(loc => req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith(`/${loc}`)) &&
    !req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/_next')
  ) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(`/${lng}${req.nextUrl.pathname}`, req.url))
  }

  if (req.headers.has('referer')) {
    const refererUrl = new URL(req.headers.get('referer'))
    const lngInReferer = languages.find((l) => refererUrl.pathname.startsWith(`/${l}`))
    const response = NextResponse.next()
    if (lngInReferer) response.cookies.set(cookieName, lngInReferer)
    return response
  }

  return NextResponse.next()
}

and the last setting js file
// /app/i18n/setting.js

export const fallbackLng = 'en'
export const languages = [fallbackLng, 'de']
export const defaultNS = 'translation'
export const cookieName = 'i18next'

export function getOptions (lng = fallbackLng, ns = defaultNS) {
  return {
    // debug: true,
    supportedLngs: languages,
    fallbackLng,
    lng,
    fallbackNS: defaultNS,
    defaultNS,
    ns,
    
  }
}

enter image description here
it should be removed
